# What is the maximum resolution monitor supported by G31 m-vs?

Tags: windows-7, display, graphics-card, resolution, graphics

I am planning on buying a 22 inch monitor which has resolution of 1920x1080. Right now I am using a CRT monitor with 1080*768 resolution. When I right click on on desktop go to Graphic Properties----> graphic settings. I can see that the maximum resolution available is "11 hundred something * something"

I have  Asrock G31 m-vs  mother board. Intel G31/33 family Chipset. No additional Graphic Card.

Will I be able to set display resolution to 1920*1080 if I get this new monitor? Or will I be limited to what I am right now?

The AsRock website says that G31 m-vs
*-supports D-Sub with max. resolution up to 2048x1536 @ 60Hz*

I am not sure if it supports 2048x1536 without any additional graphic card or with a better graphic card.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specifications given for a motherboard are specifically for **that** motherboard and do not include additional hardware that would need to be connected.

Therefore, the [specs for your board](http://www.asrock.com/mb/intel/g31m-vs/) indicate it supports 2048x1536 thru the VGA port (D-Sub). This leads me to believe that monitor will work.

***Note: Verify the proper cable interface is available from the monitor. If the monitor has a DVI connector, that will not that will not connect to you motherboard.***

This is a DVI connector:

[image]

Your motherboard uses a DB-15 (D-Sub):

[image]

> (D-SUBminiature connectors) A family of plugs and sockets widely used
>   in communications and on earlier PCs. For example, the analog VGA
>   monitor interface uses a D-sub 15-pin plug and socket. Also called "DB
>   connectors" and "D-subs," they come in 9, 15, 25, 37 and 50 pin
>   varieties. The D-sub designation defines the physical structure of the
>   connector, not the purpose of each line.

[Source](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/55439/d-sub-connectors)

Comment: The monitor I am about to buy is has D-Sub andHDMI connectivity so that should not be a problem. BUT why does I see maximum resolution available in graphic settings to be 11 hundred and not 2048x1536 ?
Are you sure that I will be able to set resolution to 1920x1080?

Comment: The monitor has a limit too. So, you may be seeing the limit the card recognizes the monitor has. By using a web site to discuss this, there is no way I can be sure of anything. I answered the best I could with the information I was given.

Comment: Well, I got the new monitor I had my eyes set on. And it worked like a charm. I did not even have to manually select 1920 x 1080 resolution. Windwows 7 prevents the user from seeing high resolution that are not supported by monitor. When I connected my new monitor with my computer it automatically set optimal resolution of the monitor. Thanks for your reply.